# How to test ajax with jsunit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jsunit

Did anybody write tests for ajax with jsunit? I don't now how to test asynchronous functions.

Could you please show me some examples?

Example.

```
I have function
var General = function() { }
General.prototype = {
limit: null,

loadData: function() {
        var url = "General.GetSessionData"
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {},
            datatype: 'json',                
            success: function(data) {
                self.limit = data;
        });
    },
}
```

How i can test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried googling? [HERE](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2005/ajar/ajaw/test/jsunit/tests/jsUnitTestSetUpPages.html) is an example test (asynchronous). The parent URL tells you how everything about JSUnit tests.

Comment: i see it, but it is not test for ajax